# Setting up a distributed computing grid on local network using .NET

Tags: distributed-computing

In our firm we run complex simulations using our own software developed in .NET. These simulations are well-suited to parallel computation and we currently make much use of the various multi-threading features native to .NET. Even so, simulations often take hours or days.

We'd like to explore the potential of distributing computation over our local network of high-performance (24 core) workstations to access more CPU power. However we have no experience in this area.

Searching on Google reveals a few MPI-based options such as Pure MPI, MPI.NET, plus some commercial software such as Frontier.

Which solution should we consider for something that is ideally well-suited to a .NET environment and is relatively easy to set up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading != grid computing, so you will need to rewrite some parts of your application regardless of what you will choose in the end.

I don’t know your network infrastructure but it sounded to me, like you would want to use normal desktop workstations to run distribute the code. I wouldn’t use MPI for that. MPI was rather developed for clusters and supercomputers where the network supports high bandwidth and low latency. Those aren’t the properties of a traditional office network (unless I understood something wrong).

The next thing you have to deal with is the fact that users shouldn’t turn off their machines if computations are performed on them. No grid computing platform (including MPI) deals with these kind of issues, as it is usually running on server hardware which has little failures and are running 24/7.

I don’t think there is a simple and inexpensive solution to this. You could have a service running on each machine which could execute code from DLLs with predefined parameters and send responses. Those assemblies could be downloadable from some windowsshare. But you want to have really huge peaces of work to be distributed like this. You wouldn’t get almost any improvements if the application runs only for a minute or less.

In the end you’d need also a service to find those services which are online or not, some kind of in memory DB where every service could write the IP address and that it’s online so that the clients would know to whom they can distribute the work. This could be done using RavenDB (as you said you are working with .Net), Redis or an application which was actually written for these kind of problems, Zookeeper.